# Iterating over distinct items in one field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a very large collection (~7M items) in MongoDB, primarily consisting of documents with three fields.

I'd like to be able to iterate over all the *unique* values for one of the fields, in an expedient manner.

Currently, I'm querying for just that field, and then processing the returned results by iterating on the cursor for uniqueness. This works, but it's rather slow, and I suspect there must be a better way.

I know mongo has the `db.collection.distinct()` function, but this is limited by the maximum BSON size (16 MB), which my dataset exceeds.

Is there any way to iterate over something similar to the `db.collection.distinct()`, but using a cursor or some other method, so the record-size limit isn't as much of an issue?

I think maybe something like the map/reduce functionality would possibly be suited for this kind of thing, but I don't really understand the map-reduce paradigm in the first place, so I have no idea what I'm doing. The project I'm working on is partially to learn about working with different database tools, so I'm rather inexperienced.

<sub>I'm using PyMongo if it's relevant (I don't think it is). This should be mostly dependent on MongoDB alone.</sub>

---

Example:

For this dataset:

```
{"basePath" : "foo", "internalPath" : "Neque", "itemhash": "49f4c6804be2523e2a5e74b1ffbf7e05"}
{"basePath" : "foo", "internalPath" : "porro", "itemhash": "ffc8fd5ef8a4515a0b743d5f52b444bf"}
{"basePath" : "bar", "internalPath" : "quisquam", "itemhash": "cf34a8047defea9a51b4a75e9c28f9e7"}
{"basePath" : "baz", "internalPath" : "est", "itemhash": "c07bc6f51234205efcdeedb7153fdb04"}
{"basePath" : "foo", "internalPath" : "qui", "itemhash": "5aa8cfe2f0fe08ee8b796e70662bfb42"}
```

What I'd like to do is iterate over *just* the `basePath` field. For the above dataset, this means I'd iterate over `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` just once each.

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the DB I have is structured so that while each field is not unique, the aggregate of all three is unique (this is enforced with an index).

---

The query and filter operation I'm currently using (note: I'm restricting the query to a subset of the items to reduce processing time):

```
    self.log.info("Running path query")
    itemCursor = self.dbInt.coll.find({"basePath": pathRE}, fields={'_id': False, 'internalPath': False, 'itemhash': False}, exhaust=True)
    self.log.info("Query complete. Processing")
    self.log.info("Query returned %d items", itemCursor.count())
    self.log.info("Filtering returned items to require uniqueness.")
    items = set()
    for item in itemCursor:
        # print item
        items.add(item["basePath"])

    self.log.info("total unique items = %s", len(items))
```

Running the same query with `self.dbInt.coll.distinct("basePath")` results in `OperationFailure: command SON([('distinct', u'deduper_collection'), ('key', 'basePath')]) failed: exception: distinct too big, 16mb cap`

---

Ok, here is the solution I wound up using. I'd add it as an answer, but I don't want to detract from the actual answers that got me here.

```
    reStr = "^%s" % fqPathBase
    pathRE = re.compile(reStr)
    self.log.info("Running path query")

    pipeline = [
        { "$match" :
            {
                "basePath" : pathRE
            }
        },
        # Group the keys
        {"$group":
            {
                "_id": "$basePath"
            }
        },

        # Output to a collection "tmp_unique_coll"
        {"$out": "tmp_unique_coll"}
        ]

    itemCursor = self.dbInt.coll.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
    itemCursor = self.dbInt.db.tmp_unique_coll.find(exhaust=True)

    self.log.info("Query complete. Processing")
    self.log.info("Query returned %d items", itemCursor.count())
    self.log.info("Filtering returned items to require uniqueness.")
    items = set()
    retItems = 0
    for item in itemCursor:
        retItems += 1
        items.add(item["_id"])


    self.log.info("Recieved items = %d", retItems)
    self.log.info("total unique items = %s", len(items))
```

General performance compared to my previous solution is about 2X in terms of wall-clock time. On a query that returns 834273 items, with 11467 uniques:

Original method(retreive, stuff into a python `set` to enforce uniqueness):

```
real    0m22.538s
user    0m17.136s
sys     0m0.324s
```

Aggregate pipeline method :

```
real    0m9.881s
user    0m0.548s
sys     0m0.096s
```

So while the overall execution time is only ~2X better, the aggregation pipeline is massively more performant in terms of actual CPU time.

---

Update:

I revisited this project recently, and rewrote the DB layer to use a SQL database, and everything was much easier. A complex processing pipeline is now a simple `SELECT DISTINCT(colName) WHERE xxx` operation.

Realistically, MongoDB and NoSQL databases in general are vary much the wrong database type for what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Some sample data maybe? Would help if we could see what we are trying to do.

Comment: Kind of. So to get this straight. "Iterate" means, you are trying to group together the *unique* values of ("basePath", "internalPath", "itemHash") combined. And even restricting to say `foo` blows up the 16MB limit. Let's say, in [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) even. Which would mean for the **result** size.

Comment: Well, I want to query for the unique values, and *then* iterate over them (is there a way to retrieve data without exceeding the BSON limit that isn't iterative?). And yes, even restricting to the `basePath` field exceeds the 16 MB limit.

Comment: Clarifying my point and kind of heading towards specifying an answer, is it likely your **result** set is larger than 16MB, and do you think the **working** set falls in between [these tolerances](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/) or have you tried already?

Comment: @NeilLunn - My result set when not-unique is ~7809961 items. When filtered to only allow unique items, it is ~672616. Each result is a string in the range of 30-100 bytes, so the overall data-set size for only unique strings is in the range of ~33 MB, assuming zero overhead. Furthermore, I'd like to be able to eventually scale up to maybe 10X the number of items I currently have, so maybe 300-400MB worst-case?

Comment: The system I'm working on has 8 GB of RAM, so staying under 10% should be viable, depending on overhead, and I can add more ram if really needed. I don't see any other restrictions on the tolerances page that are relevant, all my data is just plain strings.

Comment: Written up as an answer. Id' be interested to know if this blows up for you just with `foo` even. + I'm making notes on 2.6

Comment: @NeilLunn - Are you involved in MongoDB development? Cool!

Comment: Just an avid tester. And this is part of a bunch of JIRA issues I have followed.

Comment: Meaning get values of `basePath` grouped on the other keys? and yes I probably should have read your code sample first. Or do you **just** want all possible values of `basePath` from the whole set.

Comment: @NeilLunn - I don't care about the other keys here at all (I'm not entirely sure what "grouped on" means in this context, actually). I want a set containing *just* all values currently in `basePath`.

Comment: And sorry. [Probably really should be in chat] So just what are you filtering with that `pathRE` part? Some regex, but how?

Comment: @NeilLunn - That's somewhat unrelated, but that's just reducing the size of my result-set, by filtering for prefixes. I'm using a re to filter so I get fewer results to just keep the query and processing time down, so I don't have to wait 5 minutes to see if my changes are breaking stuff.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48138/discussion-between-neil-lunn-and-fake-name)

Comment: I expect this would work very well as a MapReduce if you just emit the `basepath` as the key.

Comment: @WiredPrairie yeah sounds like it. Just testing the limits of agg while in chat.

Comment: @WiredPrairie FYI this **only** blows up on the output size over 16MB. So feel free to write the mapReduce.

Comment: So after our long discussion and lead through, and discovering that the output size was the only actual limitation we have a result. And several approaches thanks to @WiredPrairie adding the mapReduce implementation parts in the process. Good to get a development project off and working on what will be in the next stable release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussion points so far I'm going to take a stab at this. And I'm also noting that as of writing, the 2.6 release for MongoDB should be **just around the corner**, good weather permitting, so I am going to make some references there.

Oh and the FYI that didn't come up in chat, `.distinct()` is an entirely different animal that pre-dates the methods used in the responses here, and as such is subject to **many** limitations.

> **And this soltion is finally a solution for 2.6 up, or any current dev release over 2.5.3**
>
> The alternative for now is use mapReduce because the only restriction is the output size

Without going into the inner workings of distinct, I'm going to go on the presumption that aggregate is doing this more efficiently [and even more so in upcoming release].

```
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Group the key and increment the count per match
    {$group: { _id: "$basePath", count: {$sum: 1}  }},

    // Hey you can even sort it without breaking things
    {$sort: { count: 1 }},

    // Output to a collection "output"
    {$out: "output"}

])
```

So we are using the [$out](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) pipeline stage to get the final result that is over 16MB into a collection of it's own. There you can do what you want with it.

As **2.6** is "*just around the corner*" there is one more tweak that can be added.

Use [allowDiskUse](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/aggregate/) from the `runCommand` form, where each stage can use disk and **not** be subject to memory restrictions.

The main point here, is that this is nearly live for production. And the performance will be better than the same operation in mapReduce. So go ahead and play. Install 2.5.5 for you own use now.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm describing things incorrectly. I'm not trying to iterate over all items which have `foo` as the `basepath`, I'm trying to obtain a set describing all current values for `basepath` (with no duplicates). Basically, I want what `sb.collection.distinct("basePath")` would return, if it didn't hit the 16MB limit. If that is what this does, I apparently *really* don't understand mongo.

Comment: I may be using the wrong terms here. When I say field `basepath` has the value `foo`, I would say that `key` `basepath` has the value `foo` (e.g. `key : value`). Is this at odds with the way MongoDB describes field aspects (I'm coming from python `dict`s here)?

Comment: @FakeName So does this break?

Answer (score 1):

A MapReduce, in the current version of Mongo would avoid the problems of the results exceeding 16MB.

```
map = function() {
    if(this['basePath']) {
        emit(this['basePath'], 1);
    }
    // if basePath always exists you can just call the emit:
    // emit(this.basePath);
};

reduce = function(key, values) {
    return Array.sum(values);
};
```

For each document the `basePath` is emitted with a single value representing the count of that value. The reduce simply creates the sum of all the values. The resulting collection would have all unique values for `basePath` along with the total number of occurrences.

And, as you'll need to store the results to prevent an error using the `out` option which specifies a destination collection.

```
db.yourCollectionName.mapReduce(
                 map,
                 reduce,
                 { out: "distinctMR" }
               )
```

Comment: And this is how you do it **right now**. Just spent the time testing the limits on the data set being used.

Comment: But to note, this only avoids the problem by being able to write out to a collection. So use that option when invoking the mapReduce command.

Answer (score 0):

@Neil Lunn 's answer could be simplified:

`field = 'basePath' # Field I want
db.collection.aggregate( [{'$project': {field: 1, '_id': 0}}])`

`$project` filters fields for you. In particular, `'_id': 0` filters out the `_id` field.

Result still too large? Batch it with `$limit` and `$skip`:

`field = 'basePath' # Field I want
db.collection.aggregate( [{'$project': {field: 1, '_id': 0}}, {'$limit': X}, {'$skip': Y}])`

Answer (score 0):

I think the most scalable solution is to perform a query for each unique value. The queries must be executed one after the other, and each query will give you the "next" unique value based on the previous query result. The idea is that the query will return you one single document, that will contain the unique value that you are looking for. If you use the proper projection, mongo will just use the index loaded into memory without having to read from disk.

You can define this strategy using $gt operator in mongo, but you must take into account values like null or empty strings, and potentially discard them using the $ne or $nin operator. You can also extend this strategy using multiple keys, using operators like $gte for one key and $gt for the other.

This strategy should give you the distinct values of a string field in alphabetical order, or distinct numerical values sorted ascendingly.